# JQuery PHP Survey Tool

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to create an online survey where user can make their own survey

So far I have the following:
If User clicks on a button MutlipleChoice he can add a question and as many answers as he wants.
I have the following code:

html code:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>

<!-- Add Multiple Choice Question -->
<button id="addMC">Multiplechoice Question</button>
```

my jQuery to append a div looks like this:

```
$(wrapper).append(

    //ADD TEXT FIELD FOR QUESTION
    '<div class=„mc">' + 
    '<label>Question' +qID+ '</label> '  +
    '<input type="text" name=„Question[]" id="frage_' + qID + '" placeholder="enter your question ' + qID + '"/>' 

//ADD AN ANSWER
    '<p class="radiobutton_child" id="radioButton' + aID +'“>' + 
    '<input type="radio" name="myradio" id="radio"/>' +
    '<input type="text" name=„Answer[]"  id="antwort_' + aID +'" placeholder="enter your answer"/>’ </p> +
    '</div>‘);
```

by clicking on an add button the user can add more radio buttons for a possible answer

if he clicks on the button Multiple Choice Question he can create Question number 2

now I need to save all these questions and answers in a database.

to save the Questions I loop through the Question[]. E.g I have created 2 questions, this 2 Questions are stored in my database.

```
foreach ( $_POST["Question"] as $key=>$value ) {

…… Insert into database

}
```

My problem is, if for example question 1 has 2 possible answers and question 2 has 3 possible answers then it always stores 5 answers to question 1 and 5 answers to question 2

My DB looks like this.

```
Question Table:
questionID
question


Answer Table:
answerID
answer
questionID
```

How can I store the answers related to the questions in the database? Or am I doing this in the wrong way?

Comment: my answers db table has an foreign key. questionID ist the foreign key of the answers table. My problem is if I loop through Answer[] like I do it with questions the answers are not stored correctly.

Comment: Try adding question index to answer name field `Answer[2][]`

Comment: Expectet result should be: Question 1: What's your favourite seasson of year? Answers1 Summer, Answer2: Winter, Answer3: fall, Answer4: spring. Quesition2: Whats your favourite color? Answer1: red, Answer2: blue. Now I wan't to store in question Table: questionID=1 with question whats your favourite seasson of the year. questionID=2 whats your favourite color. and in Answer table: answerID1=1 winter questionID=1, answerID=2 fall questionID=1, answerID=3 spring questionID=1, answerID=4 summer questionID=1, answerID=5 red questionID=2, answerID=6 blue

Comment: could you explain me please what you mean with adding question index to answer name field?

Comment: see example above .... try it and do a var_dump of request